# Pandas cut dataframe to intervals, then get value if in interval

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and cut it based on the values in col1 into 10 quantiles:

```
pd.qcut(df.col1, [0,.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9,1])
```

This creates a pandas series of intervals.

Afterwards I want to create a list of lists

```
[['col2 values where col1 in quantile1'],['col2 values where col1 in quantile2'],...]
```

from all the values in col2, which lie within the before created intervals somehow like:

```
qcut = pd.qcut(df.col1, [0,.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9,1])

qlist = [[None]*len(qcut)]

for i in range(len(qcut)+1):
    qlist[[i]].append(df.col2.loc[qcut.iloc[i].left < df.col1 < qcut.iloc[i].right])
```

Unfortunately I can't find the correct boolean operation for determining if a value is within an interval.

Thanks in advance if you know the operator or have a better idea.

Comment: First, this question is very vague and without example data and your expected output, it's hard to know what you want. Second, it's weird that you want a dataframe of lists, as that's not really what dataframes are optimized to contain. Lastly: `df.groupby(qcut)['col2].apply(list)`

Comment: Hi Paul, I want to split the dataframe afterwards based on the lists of values from col2. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: If the wiki for the pandas tag, there a link to a question about making reproducible pandas examples for questions like yours. I suggest you read it.

Comment: I thought the problem was casual enough to not need an example df. And it seems to have been. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I'm still unclear what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.groupby(qcut)['col2'].apply(list)
```

by @Paul H did it. Simply grouping the dataframe by the cut for col2 and applying this as a list

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're doing quantiles, every row will fall into a quantile. To group a column by the quantile of another column, just scan the column searching for changes in quantile and save the list in each group.

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
   {'col1':[x for x in range(50)],  # 0-49
    'col2':[str(chr(x+65)) for x in range(50)]}  # ascii 65-114
)

qc = pd.qcut(df.col1, [0,.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9,1])  # 10 quantiles

all = []  # full list
lst = []  # each quantile
last = ''
for z in zip(df['col2'], qc):
   if z[1] != last:  # next quantile
      all.append(lst)
      lst = [z[0]]  # start new list
      last = z[1]
   else:
      lst.append(z[0])  # same quantile
      
      
all.append(lst)  # final quantile
del all[0]  # remove blank

print(df)
print(qc)
print(all)
```

Output

```
    col1 col2
0      0    A
1      1    B
2      2    C
3      3    D
4      4    E
5      5    F
6      6    G
......

0      (-0.001, 4.9]
1      (-0.001, 4.9]
2      (-0.001, 4.9]
3      (-0.001, 4.9]
4      (-0.001, 4.9]
5        (4.9, 81.8]
6        (4.9, 81.8]
......

[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 
 ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'], 
 ['K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O'], 
 ['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T'], 
 ['U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y'], 
 ['Z', '[', '\', ']', '^'], 
 ['_', '`', 'a', 'b', 'c'], 
 ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], 
 ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm'], 
 ['n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r']]
```

Comment: Hi Mike, the answer of @Paul H actually already did the trick. Still thanks for your answer